# fetching the data with spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

im still beginner with java and spring , i have already stored table in mysql named as `Offers`, im trying to fetch the data row by row `where the Status == 0`, my table looks like:

```
-------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+
| Msisdn      | Entry_Date | Start_Date | End_Date   | Service_Type | Status | Parm_1 | Parm_2 | Parm_3 | Process_Date |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+
| 7777777777  | 2019-01-11 | 2019-02-15 | 2019-03-03 | 1            |      1 | 1      | 1      | 1      | 2019-10-15   |
| 7888888899  | 2019-01-11 | 2019-02-12 | 2019-03-03 | 1            |      0 | 1      | 1      | 1      | 2019-10-15   |
| 799999999   | 2019-01-11 | 2019-02-10 | 2019-03-03 | 1            |      0 | 1      | 1      | 1      | 2019-10-15   |
| 79111111111 | 2019-01-28 | 2019-02-27 | 2019-03-03 | 1            |      0 | 1      | 1      | 1      | 2019-10-15   |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------
```

when i try to run my code its return

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity:
>   com.example.accessingdatajpa.Offers

Offers

```
package com.example.accessingdatajpa;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;


@Entity
public class Offers {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String Msisdn;
    private String Entry_Date;
    private String Start_Date;
    private String End_Date;
    private String Service_Type;
    private String Status;
    private String Parm_1;
    private String Parm_2;
    private String Parm_3;
    private String Process_Date;

    protected Offers() {}

    public Offers(String Msisdn, String Entry_Date, String Start_Date, String End_Date, String Service_Type, String Status, String Parm_1 ,String Parm_2, String Parm_3, String Process_Date) {
        this.Msisdn = Msisdn;
        this.Entry_Date = Entry_Date;
        this.Start_Date = Start_Date;
        this.End_Date = End_Date;
        this.Service_Type = Service_Type;
        this.Status = Status;
        this.Parm_1 = Parm_1;
        this.Parm_2 = Parm_2;
        this.Parm_3 = Parm_3;
        this.Process_Date = Process_Date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Offers[Msisdn='%s', Entry_Date='%s', Start_Date='%s', End_Date='%s', Service_Type='%s', Status='%s', Parm_1='%s', Parm_2='%s', Parm_3='%s',Process_Date='%s']",
                Msisdn, Entry_Date, Start_Date, End_Date, Service_Type, Status, Parm_1,Parm_2,Parm_3,Process_Date);
    }

    public String getMsisdn() {
        return Msisdn;
    }

    public String getProcess_Date() {
        return Process_Date;
    }

    public String getEntry_Date() {
        return Entry_Date;
    }

    public String getStart_Date() {
        return Start_Date;
    }

    public String getEnd_Date() {
        return End_Date;
    }

    public String getService_Type() {
        return Service_Type;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public String getParm_1() {
        return Parm_1;
    }

    public String getParm_2() {
        return Parm_2;
    }

    public String getParm_3() {
        return Parm_3;
    }
}
```

OffersRepository

```
package com.example.accessingdatajpa;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface OffersRepository extends CrudRepository<Offers, String> {

    List<Offers> findByStatus(String Status);

    Offers findByMsisdn(String Msisdn);
}
```

AccessingDataJpaApplication

```
package com.example.accessingdatajpa;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AccessingDataJpaApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(OffersRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {

            // fetch by status =0
            log.info("Offers found with findByStatus('0'):");
            log.info("--------------------------------------------");
            repository.findByStatus("0").forEach(on -> {
                log.info(on.toString());
            });
            log.info("");
        };
    }

}
```

test file

```
package com.example.accessingdatajpa;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class OffersRepositoryTests {
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private OffersRepository offer;

    @Test
    public void testFindByStatus() {
        Offers Offer = new Offers();
        entityManager.persist(Offer);

        List<Offers> findByStatus = offer.findByStatus(Offer.getStatus());

        assertThat(findByStatus).extracting(Offers::getStatus).containsOnly(Offer.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do like
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String Msisdn;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see quite few mistakes there:

**1st**

Add `@Id` annotation to `msisdn`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private String Msisdn;
```

**2nd**

Add `@Repository` annotation to `OffersRepository`

```
@Repository
public interface OffersRepository extends CrudRepository<Offers, String> {

    List<Offers> findByStatus(String Status);

    Offers findByMsisdn(String Msisdn);
}
```

**3rd**

Add an autowired bean of type `OffersRepository` to your `AccessingDataJpaApplication` class and remove the parameter `OffersRepository repository` from your method `public CommandLineRunner demo(OffersRepository repository)`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AccessingDataJpaApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private OffersRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo() {
        return (args) -> {

            // fetch by status =0
            log.info("Offers found with findByStatus('0'):");
            log.info("--------------------------------------------");
            repository.findByStatus("0").forEach(on -> {
                log.info(on.toString());
            });
            log.info("");
        };
    }

}
```

**4th**

If you want to use `CommandLineRunner`, you need to implement it. You can do in a very simple way, by just implementing in your bootstrap class.

**AccessingDataJpaApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AccessingDataJpaApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private OffersRepository repository;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) {
        log.info("Offers found with findByStatus('0'):");
        log.info("--------------------------------------------");
        repository.findByStatus("0").forEach(on - >{
            log.info(on.toString());
        });
        log.info("");
    }

}
```

Comment: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessingDataJpaApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with

Comment: name 'offersRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.accessingdatajpa.OffersRepository.findByStatus(java.lang.String)! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [status] on this ManagedType [com.example.accessingdatajpa.Offers]

Comment: By convention, usually properties starts with lower case. Rename the property `Status` to `status` in your `Offers` class. `private String status`

Comment: thank you its worked , but  the problem it does not print out the result on the console

Comment: Well, that's because you're not printing anything to the console. If you want to use CommandLineRunner, you need to implement it. I've updated my answer. Take a look

Comment: thank you its worked fine , can you help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58582177/jpa-with-https-request-multithreading-spring/58584987#58584987

Answer (score 0):

Offers has no primary key. You have to annotate the primary key attribute with @Id

Like

```
@Id
private Integer id;
```

Comment: its return this warning each time i run code : Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-16 16:13:01.855 ERROR 16835 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demo' defined in com.example.accessingdatajpa.AccessingDataJpaApplication: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'demo' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factor

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private String Msisdn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a field annotated with `@Id`. Each `@Entity` needs an `@Id` - this is given to the primary key in the database. On your entity class specify the annotations like :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OFFERS")
public class Offers {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "Msisdn")
   private String Msisdn;

   @Column(name = "Entry_Date")   
   private String Entry_Date;

   @Column(name = "Start_Date")
   private String Start_Date;

   @Column(name = "End_Date")
   private String End_Date;

   @Column(name = "Service_Type")
   private String Service_Type;

   @Column(name = "Status")
   private String Status;

   @Column(name = "Parm_1")
   private String Parm_1;

   @Column(name = "Parm_2")
   private String Parm_2;

   @Column(name = "Parm_3")
   private String Parm_3;

   @Column(name = "Process_Date")
   private String Process_Date;
   //Setters and getters
}
```

It is okay , not to specify the table and column using the annotation if your column and table name **adhers to the Implicit naming strategy.**

> The placement of the @Id annotation marks the persistence state access
>   strategy.The identifier uniquely identifies each row in that table. By 
>   default, the name of the table is assumed to be the same as the name
>   of the entity. To explicitly give the name of the table or to specify
>   other information about the table, we would use the
>   javax.persistence.Table annotation.A logical name can be either explicitly 
>   specified by the user (using @Column or @Table e.g.) or it can be
>   implicitly determined by Hibernate through an ImplicitNamingStrategy
>   contract.

Official [Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity).

Comment: can you help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58582177/jpa-with-https-request-multithreading-spring/58584987#58584987